# Can someone help with this horrible curve for the path of the sun?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

So I am doing some astronomical calculations for fun and it turns out that the approximate path that the sun traces in the sky should look something like:
$$
\Gamma(t) = \left(\arctan\left(\frac{c_{i}\sin\left(t\right)}{c_{l}s_{i}-s_{l}c_{i}\cos\left(t\right)}\right), \frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos\left(c_{l}c_{i}\cos\left(t\right)+s_{l}s_{i}\right)\right) =: (\alpha(t),\beta(t))
$$
where $c_i, s_i, c_l, s_l$ are constants (sine and cosine of the Earth inclination and my location's latitude) so that $s^2_i+c^2_i=s^2_l+c^2_l=1$.

The component $\alpha(t)$ should be the clockwise angle that the sun makes with the South direction at time $t$ (the azimuth minus $\pi$) and $\beta(t)$ is the angular height at time $t$. The time $t=0$ represents the local noon.

The algebraic formulation of the path is horrible. Plotting $\Gamma(t)$ for each of the 12 months (i.e. changing the parameters $c_i$ and $s_i$) the 6 resulting paths (there are 6 paths because each path counts for 2 different months, the lowest path is December-January, the highest is June-July) are relatively nice looking continuous curves:

[image]

but (due to the mean $\arccos(t)$ I guess) I had to stitch together *four* traslated versions of $\Gamma$ to make this picture, that is:
\begin{align*}
(\alpha(t),\beta(t))\quad &|\quad-\pi<t<0,\quad&\alpha(t) > 0 \\
(\alpha(t),\beta(t))\quad &|\quad 0<t<\pi,\quad&\alpha(t) < 0 \\
(\alpha(t)-\pi,\beta(t))\quad &|\quad 0<t<\pi,\quad&\alpha(t) > 0 \\
(\alpha(t)+\pi,\beta(t))\quad &|\quad-\pi<t<0,\quad&\alpha(t) < 0
\end{align*}
Is there a way to somewhat "prettify" the poor $\Gamma(t)$ and plot it as a single path?

Comment: $\Gamma(t)$ looks fine to me.

Comment: Perhaps replacing the $\arctan$ with an [$\operatorname{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) expression would help.

Comment: @Blue Useful! How commonly is `atan2` used in mathematics (as opposed to computing & engineering)?

Comment: @ryang: *"How commonly is `atan2` used in mathematics?"* That's a good question, to which I have no good answer. I personally have been using it more because it's *awfully* convenient, but I'm both a mathematician and a coder. (The mathy side of me would prefer the notation $\operatorname{arg}(x,y)$, as the result is the argument of complex number $x+yi$.) However, a [search of Math.SE for `atan2`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=atan2) yields only about $850$ results (out of literally *millions* of questions and answers), which suggests that the function is not (yet) widely adopted.

Comment: @Blue Thanks too for the `arg(x,y)` suggestion; come to think of it, that still feels rather computer science, and mathematicians might instead write `arg(x+iy)`.

Comment: @ryang: Well, mathematicians *do* write `arg(x+iy)` in the context of complex numbers. :) Using `arg(x+iy)` outside of that context is problematic. (*Arg*uably, most people who might have use for the function have that need well before they ever encounter complex numbers.) Besides, as with `atan2`, the whole purpose of the function is to *de-couple* $x$ and $y$. (Since comments are not the appropriate place for discussion, I'll consider these my final words on the topic.) Cheers!